# Deep Learning Model Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to create a CNN model to predict head injury. I have identified the spectrogram images for my datasets and also created label file indicating head injury or not.
I took two dataset, both have columns: Channel, Label and Image Path. Label as 1(indicate head injury) and 0(indicate non-injury). A total of 117 channels images was identified from each dataset. While trying to run a CNN model i used the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EEG Processing Material/div_attention.cnt spectrogram images/Updated Head Injury Labels.csv') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EEG Processing Material/1c_p300 spectrogram images/Updated Head Injury Labels 2.csv')  

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

df['Label'] = df['Label'].astype(str)

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

train_df['Label'] = train_df['Label'].astype(str)
test_df['Label'] = test_df['Label'].astype(str)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    x_col='Image_Path',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=(1000, 800),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_df,
    x_col='Image_Path',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=(1000, 800),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Till this part it gave me output as:

Found 186 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Found 47 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.

```
#Create Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1000, 800, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

OUTPUT:

[Model Summary:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skR0W.png)

#Train the model

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=test_generator.n // test_generator.batch_size
)
```

OUTPUT:
[Model training output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skR0W.png)

After model training code, my kernal automatically dies showing ResourceExhausted error, how do i fix this? I also tried to run in Google colab, and there also i faced the similar error.

Comment: Add the full error traceback.

Comment: And please don't use images, but copy the full text into the questions. [Why you should not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15019223)